# 2 dimension list in kotlin casted to com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

So im new to kotlin and have just migrated my code from java to kotlin. I have a data class HistoryList that is used to parse a response from an API.

```
data class HistoryList(
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    var code: String = "",

    @SerializedName("historyByDate")
    @Expose
    var histories : List<List<History>>
)
```

but when I tried to parse histories and access the second list for example `histories[0][0]`. the return was casted to `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`. I tried to investigate the data class and tried decompile it to java this is what i get.

```
public final class HistoryList {
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    @NotNull
    private String code;

    @SerializedName("historyByDate")
    @Expose
    @NotNull
    private List histories;

}
```

as you notice the histories in the decompiled code became a list and im guessing it should be

```
List<List<Histories>> histories;
```

Can anyone explain to me:

-how did the decompiled class became like this

-why does `histories[0][0]` gets casted to `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`. 
-how to properly parse the data class

BTW before using this data class it was working well when i was still using it in java. Accessing `histories[0][0]` returned an instance of History

**UPDATE**
I forgot to include the json i'am parsing. Thanks for pointing that out Alexey Soshin.

```
{
    "code": "success",
    "historyByDate": [
    [
        {
            "charge": 73728,
            "action": "DATA"              
        },
        {
            "charge": 105472,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 14336,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 101376,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 0,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 15360,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 18432,
            "action": "DATA"              
        },
        {
            "charge": 1060864,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 700416,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 7168,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 0,
            "action": "DATA"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "charge": 0,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 0,
            "action": "DATA"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "charge": 0,
            "action": "DATA"
        },
        {
            "charge": 0,
            "action": "DATA"
        }
    ]
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question, how did the decompiled class became like this, it's called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

To your second question, though. I didn't manage to reproduce the error.
You didn't specify what your `History` class looks like, so I just used:

`data class History(val a: String, val b: Int)`

And also you didn't specify how exactly you parse the JSON, so here's what I did:

```
val list = HistoryList("myHistoryList",
        listOf(
            listOf(History("a", 1), History("b", 2)),
            listOf(History("c", 3), History("d", 4), History("e", 5))
        ))

    val gson = Gson()
    val historyAsJson = gson.toJson(list)

    println(historyAsJson)
    // Results in {"code":"myHistoryList","historyByDate":[[{"a":"a","b":1},{"a":"b","b":2}],[{"a":"c","b":3},{"a":"d","b":4},{"a":"e","b":5}]]}

    val historyAsObject = gson.fromJson(historyAsJson, HistoryList::class.java)

    // Making sure that it's indeed History object
    val h: History = historyAsObject.histories[0][0]
    println(h)
```

As you can see, I use `gson.fromJson(historyAsJson, HistoryList::class.java)` for the conversion, and `historyAsObject.histories[0][0]` works as expected.

Comment: this is weird. i tried parsing just like what you did through a static json string and its working. but whenever i tried parsing it directly from an api response i still get the error com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to History. Honestly the way you parse the json is the same with mine but im not sure why im getting different results.

Comment: JSON you've posted won't be parsed by Gson, at least by default, because it has trailing commas. But I guess you just obfuscated it a bit. Try using `JsonParser().parse()`, because my guess is that JSON you receive is malformed somewhere.

Comment: i think theres an issue on my parsing in my main project. i tried parsing the json response from a new project and it is working.

Comment: well i had some progress so far. I was now able to parse historyAsObject.histories[0][0] but when im accessing the some field inside im now getting LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to history error. especially doing this val h: History = historyAsObject.histories[0][0]